# Aggregate raster using gaussian smoothing as a custom function/Units of the sigma

Tags: raster, r, function, terra, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate a raster using a custom function and the `terra` package. For the custom function I am using a `Gaussian smoothing`. When I try to run the aggregate function I am getting this error: `Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : object 'fun' of mode 'function' was not found`. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(terra)

fr = rast("path/fr.tif")

matg = focalMat(fr, 
                0.5 * 500, 
                "Gauss")

ra = aggregate(fr, 
               fact = 5, 
               fun = matg)

writeRaster(ra, 
            "path/fr_aggr.tif", 
            overwrite = TRUE)
```

My raster:

```
fr = rast(ncols=222, nrows=205, nlyrs=1, xmin=4831500, xmax=4853700, ymin=3856600, ymax=3877100, names=c('B10_median'), crs='EPSG:7755')
```

After I tried the code from the answer below, I am getting this error: Error: [focal] test failed

Here is what I tried:

```
r = rast("path/fr.tif")

lin.conv <- function (y,K) {
  if(inherits(y, "matrix"))
    y <- as.vector(y)  
  K <- K / sum(K)
  X <- as.matrix(Matrix::bandSparse(length(y), 
                                    k = seq(-(length(K)-1),0,1), 
                                    diag = t(replicate(length(y), rev(K))), 
                                    symm=FALSE))
  out <- X %*% as.matrix(y, ncol=1)
  return(as.vector(out))
}

fconv <- function(x, sdv=0.2*500) {
  n <- floor((sqrt(1 + 8 * length(x)) - 1)/2)-1
  y <- gaussian.kernel(sigma=sdv, s = n)
  lcv <- lin.conv(x,y)
  return( lcv[ceiling(length(lcv)/2)] )
}

rgs <- focal(r, matrix(1,5,5), fun=fconv) #here is the error
```

Comment: The `focalMat` is creating a Gaussian Kernel (matrix), not a function (eg., mean) which is what `aggregate` is expecting. I think that you want to apply your kernel function to `focal` and then aggregate the results to something approximating your kernel size. You could also write a function that applies the Gaussian weights to the pixels being aggregated but, it would have to match the number of pixels being considered but the specified `fact` and you will need to figure out what is happening within the function, is it operating on a vector or matrix, and tailor you function accordingly.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to achieve, i.e., to write a function that applies the Gaussian weights to the pixels being aggregated. Could you recommend on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this at the source resolution via a focal function and then aggregate using the mean (it will already be normal). I would make the argument that, from a smoothing perspective, one could achieve good results by skipping Gaussian decomposition and just apply a smoothing spline or local polynomial regression. This would be the nonparametric analog. Anyway, here is an approach that uses a linear matrix convolution for the Gaussian decomposition.

First, here are the needed packages, a function to perform the convolution and one to apply it within a focal function.

```
library(terra)
library(spatialEco)

lin.conv <- function (y,K) {
  if(inherits(y, "matrix"))
    y <- as.vector(y)  
    K <- K / sum(K)
    X <- as.matrix(Matrix::bandSparse(length(y), 
           k = seq(-(length(K)-1),0,1), 
           diag = t(replicate(length(y), rev(K))), 
           symm=FALSE))
    out <- X %*% as.matrix(y, ncol=1)
  return(as.vector(out))
}

fconv <- function(x, sdv=2) {
  n <- floor((sqrt(1 + 8 * length(x)) - 1)/2)-1
  y <- gaussian.kernel(sigma=sdv, s = n)
  lcv <- lin.conv(x,y)
  return( lcv[ceiling(length(lcv)/2)] )
}
```

Before we apply it within focal, let's take a look at what it is doing first. Here we create a 5x5 matrix (emulating what would be a single focal operation) and a Gaussian kernel of the same dimensions. We then apply the linear convolution and plot the results. The black point represents what would be the estimated focal value.

```
( x <- matrix(runif(25),ncol=5,nrow=5) )
y <- gaussian.kernel(sigma=2.5, s = 5)
lcv <- lin.conv(x,y)
( v <- lcv[ceiling(length(lcv)/2)] )
  dev.new(width=11,height=8.5)
    plot(as.vector(x), type="l", lty=3)
      lines(1:length(x), lcv, col="red")
      points(x=which(lcv %in% v), y=v, 
             pch=20, cex=2)
```

[image: smoothed distribution]

Now that we have an inkling that this is, in fact, applying a smoothing function we can apply it to a raster and plot the results.

```
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
  rgs <- focal(r, matrix(1,5,5), fun=fconv)
    plot(c(r, rgs))
```

[image: smoothed elevation]

Then, you can aggregate the smoothed results. Since you have applied a Gaussian smoothing, the aggregated pixels will be normal so, the mean should be a stable metric for aggregating to a coarser resolution. Since  it is sort of functioning as a focal operator you can pass our focal decomposition function directly to `aggregate` as well (which is what I believe you are after).

```
agg.rgs <- aggregate(rgs, fact = 3, fun ="mean") # OR
agg.rgs <- aggregate(r, fact = 3, fun =fconv)
  plot(agg.rgs)
```

[image: smoothed aggregated results]

Comment: The reason I chose Gaussian smoothing over other smoothers (splines etc) is because I am trying to simulate coarse data with a point spread function, which I assume is Gaussian (according to the literature).

Comment: Generally speaking, yes Gaussian is assumed however, this is not a given https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21164793/ You are correct, for your application, other smoothing functions such as splines would not be appropriate.

Comment: I edited my question because I'm getting this error when I try your code: `error: Error: [focal] test failed`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Nikos I am not getting this error here but am elsewhere and am trying to track down what is going on. I think it may be a bug in the test function used to evaluate if a passed function can run under focal. I am able to recreate very inconstant results where I can run a something outside of a function but, exactly the same code will not run inside a function and I get this error. I reran the example and am not getting it here, are you or only on your data?

Comment: I tested it with the raster I shared plus one other image. I got the same error.